# Nodejs Mongo insert into subdocument - dynamic fieldname

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoskin

{username:'me', companies:{"yourcompany":{...}}

I want to insert a company into a user record (user collection), to make:

{username:'me', companies:{ "yourcompany":{...}, "mycompany":{...} }

But the name is dynamic..

```
var companyid = "mycompany";

.collection('users').findAndModify(
{username: usern}, 
[['_id', 'asc']], 
{$set:{companies:{companyid: { desksmemberships:[] }}}},    
{new: true}, function(){...}
```

Gives this..  {username:'me', companies:{ "yourcompany":{...}, "companyid":{...} }

How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd have to build up your `$set` modifier programmatically:

```
var modifier = { $set: {} };
modifier.$set['companies.' + companyid] = { desksmemberships:[] };
```

And then use `modifier` as the third parameter in your `findAndModify` call.

You may also want to consider changing `companies` to be an array instead of an embedded object.

**Node.js 4.x Update**

You can now use the [computed property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) syntax to do this directly in the object literal:

```
collection('users').findAndModify(
    {username: usern}, 
    [['_id', 'asc']], 
    {$set:{['companies.' + companyid]: { desksmemberships:[] }}},    
    {new: true},
    function(){...});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this question on quite a few posts, some of them quite complex- call me crazy but you can do this (node + mongo):

My db schema 'matches' is set to an array. In the mongo data [match.matchId] becomes '2028856183'.

```
db.update({key: value}, {matches: [{[match.matchId] : match}] }, callback);
db.update(what to find, what to change it to, what to do next)
```

You can use any variable in the brackets.