# Update and/or add array element properties using req.body via Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have the following document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("503b83dfad79cc8d26000004"),
    "pdfs" : [
        {
            "title" : "Test document",
            "pdf_id" : ObjectId("504f6793ce351a595d000004"),
            "created_at" : ISODate("2012-09-11T16:32:19.276Z")
        },
        {
            "title" : "Some other doc",
            "pdf_id" : ObjectId("502bf124b4642341230003f0"),
            "created_at" : ISODate("2012-09-11T11:34:19.276Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

Now in an incoming form via `req.body`, I have 2 fields: `title` and `description`.

I want to update `title` and insert `description` for a specified pdf_id, how do I do that?

So in the end, my document will now look like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("503b83dfad79cc8d26000004"),
    "pdfs" : [
        {
            "title" : "This is an UPDATED title",
            "description" : "It has an ALL NEW description",
            "pdf_id" : ObjectId("504f6793ce351a595d000004"),
            "created_at" : ISODate("2012-09-11T16:32:19.276Z")
        },
        {
            "title" : "Some other doc",
            "pdf_id" : ObjectId("502bf124b4642341230003f0"),
            "created_at" : ISODate("2012-09-11T11:34:19.276Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

Just to be clear, I'm really just looking for the Mongoose `update` syntax.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`$` positional operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-The$positionaloperator) to refer to the matched `pdfs` array element in your `$set`:

```
Model.update(
    { 'pdfs.pdf_id': pdf_id }, 
    { $set: { 
        'pdfs.$.title': title, 
        'pdfs.$.description': description 
    }}, function (err, numAffected) { ... }
);
```

Comment: In the `$set`, is there any way to assign those properties dynamically? The user may not supply some, and I'd prefer to not have to specify them explicitly.

Comment: Sure, you'd just need to build up that `$set` object programmatically and then pass that object in as the second parameter to the `update` call.  Sort of like in this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184626/nodejs-mongo-insert-into-subdocument-dynamic-fieldname/12185214#12185214

Comment: Cool, thanks. Something that tripped me up, that might help others: It wouldn't update for me when I just had my array set to mixed `[]`. I had to built out the schema for the array and make sure that the _id of the array element you're trying to update is specified as a `type: Schema.Types.ObjectId` in your schema.