# Node.js - Mongoose - Update nested array with all values in req.body

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have an object that looks like this.

```
{
  _id: '577fe7a842c9b447',
  name: 'Jacob\'s Bronze Badges',
  competitors: [
    {
      _id: '577fe7a842c9bd6d',
      name: 'Peter\'s Silver Badges',
      sites: [
        {
          _id: '577fe7a842c9bd6d',
          name: 'Facebook',
          url: 'fb.com/peter'
        },
        {
          _id: '577fe7a842c9bd6d'
          name: 'Google',
          url: 'google.com/peter'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      _id: '599fe7a842c9bd6d',
      name: 'Paul\'s Gold Badges',
      sites: [
        {
          '_id': '577fe7a842c9bd6d',
          name: 'Facebook',
          url: 'fb.com/paul'
        },
        {
          _id: '577fe7a842c9bd6d',
          name: 'Google',
          url: 'google.com/paul'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My goal is to reference the `competitors` array and update items inside with all of the values from `req.body`. I based this code off of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23577123/update-nested-array-with-mongoose-mongodb) answer, as well as [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691224/mongoose-update-values-in-array-of-objects).

```
Location.update(
  { 'competitors._id': req.params.competitorId, },
  { $set: { 'competitors.$': req.body, }, },
  (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500)
      .json({ error: 'Unable to update competitor.', });
    } else {
      res.status(200)
      .json(result);
    }
  }
);
```

I send my `HTTP PUT` to `localhost:3000/competitors/577fe7a842c9bd6d` to update Peter's Silver Badges. The request body is:

```
{
  "name": "McDonald's"
}
```

The problem is that when I use `$set` to set the competitor with `_id: req.params.competitorId`, I don't know what is in `req.body`. I want to use the entire `req.body` to update the object in the array, but when I do, that object is overwritten, so instead of getting a new name, Peter's Silver Badges becomes:

```
{
  name: 'McDonald\'s',
  sites: []
}
```

How can I update an object within an array when I know the object's `_id` with all of the fields from `req.body` without removing fields that I want to keep?

I believe that the `sites` array is empty because the object was reinitialized. In my schema I have `sites: [sitesSchema]` to initialize it. So I am assuming that the whole `competitors[_id]` object is getting overwritten with the new name and then the `sites: [sitesSchema]` from myschema.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You would need to use the `$` positional operator in your `$set`. In order to assign those properties dynamically, based on what is in your `req.body`, you would need to build up your `$set` programmatically.

If you want to update the name you would do the following:

```
Location.update(
  { 'competitors._id': req.params.competitorId },
  { $set:  { 'competitors.$.name': req.body.name }},
  (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500)
      .json({ error: 'Unable to update competitor.', });
    } else {
      res.status(200)
      .json(result);
    }
 }
);
```

One way you might programatically build up the `$set` using `req.body` is by doing the following:

```
let updateObj = {$set: {}};
for(var param in req.body) {
  updateObj.$set['competitors.$.'+param] = req.body[param];
 }
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12374934/5737121) answer for more details.

Comment: yes it is working but in my code i have to send two request for a query to exexute it.
```

Answer (score 3):

To update embedded document with $ operator, in most of the cases, you have to use dot notation on the $ operator.

```
Location.update(
  { _id: '577fe7a842c9b447', 'competitors._id': req.params.competitorId, },
  { $set: { 'competitors.$.name': req.body.name, }, },
  (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500)
      .json({ error: 'Unable to update competitor.', });
    } else {
      res.status(200)
      .json(result);
    }
  }
);
```