# How can I update a MongoDB collection using a JS/JSON object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection that I'm looking to update. At the moment, I can only update it if I specifically set which values I want to update - for example:

```
  $set: {someVariable: someValue}
```

I would like to update using an object - so for instance if I had:

```
   data = {someVariable1: someValue, someVariable2: someValue}
```

and I passed it into the `$set` parameter, it should update those parameters.

Is there a way of doing this? At the moment if I just pass that data into the `$set` parameter, it adds on an extra value like so:

```
"_id" : "xxxxxxxxxx",
"someVariable1": "someValue", 
"someVariable2": "someValue",
"data" : {
    "someVariable1": "someValue", 
    "someVariable2": "someValue"
}
```

Here's my code snippet:

```
db.collection('test').updateOne(
        {_id: id},
        {
            $set: {
                data
            },
            $currentDate: {
                "lastModified": true
            }
        }, (err, result) => {
            assert.equal(err, null);
            callback(null, result);
        }
    )
```

where data is as above.

This is in Node.js by the way.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24986026/how-to-dynamically-set-a-subdocument-field-in-mongodb)

you can accomplish it by removing the brackets around data:

```
$set: data,
$currentDate: {
    "lastModified": true
}
```