# How to use variable as Object Key

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

In this function I pass in an ID variable and a name variable, I use the ID to pick out the correct table and want to set an array using the value inside of the `name` variable. Currently It's adding just "name" as an object key, how can I tell it to use the value inside of my name variable as the Object Key?

```
function addnewuser(name, id){ // add users
          console.log(id);
          db.collection('newcon').update({_id: id}, {"$set": { name: [] }});
          ret(id);
        }
```

Comment: You probably will need to [build $set modifier programmatically][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184626/nodejs-mongo-insert-into-subdocument-dynamic-fieldname

Comment: @kaaposc When I write this it is throwing an error back at me: https://gist.github.com/InternetExplorer7/199e5f6ed5ff719c0d04

Comment: You would use the `modifier` that you've defined outside like this: `db.collection('newcon').update({_id: id}, modifier);`